# how do I reorder some XML in my ajax response for better reporting

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have struggled with this a bit, and have re-framed my question to the bare necessities. I have a script that retrieves via ajax a XML feed from a SQL database. I can't really structure how it is produced, it comes from a stored procedure that I can not alter. There are some duplicate nodes in the XML. What I need to do is regroup this so I can output the a different view of the data on my page.

Here is the data:

```
    <tcm:ListPublishItems xmlns:tcm="http://xxxx">
<tcm:PublicationTarget xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:0-2-65537" Title="ProdPreview">
    <tcm:Page ID="tcm:17-999999-64" Title="testpage" Path="\usweb\wr\aps\jtest" Icon="T64LRE0">
        </tcm:Page>
    <tcm:Page ID="tcm:17-222222-64" Title="singletest" Path="\usweb\wr\aps\jtest\single" Icon="T64LRE0">
        </tcm:Page>
</tcm:PublicationTarget>
<tcm:PublicationTarget xmlns:tcm="http://xxxx" ID="tcm:0-65-65537" Title="TestPreview">
    <tcm:Page ID="tcm:17-999999-64" Title="testpage" Path="usweb\wr\aps\jtest" Icon="T64LRE0">
        </tcm:Page>
</tcm:PublicationTarget>
```

In this example There are 2 PublicationTarget nodes, one with 2 pages, and 1 with one page. In the 2nd node the page is the same page as the first node. What i need to do is output the content so it is page centric not PublicationTarget centreit

ie 
Page tcm:17-999999-64 - PubTargets - ProdPreview, TestPreview
Page tcm:17-222222-64 - PubTargets - ProdPreivew

My code

```
function parseITPData(data){
    var xmlDoc = $j.parseXML(data.d);
    var $xml = $j(xmlDoc);
    var items = $xml.find("Page");
    var newHtml = ""
    var storage = {};
    var pTCM,targetType,title,path;
    for (var i =0; i<items.length; i++) {
        pTCM = items[i].getAttribute("ID");
        targetType = items[i].parentNode.getAttribute("Title");
        path = items[i].getAttribute("Path");
        title  = items[i].getAttribute("Title");

        if ( pTCM in storage ) {
            storage[pTCM].push(targetType);     
            console.log ("nope");
        }
    else {
        storage[pTCM] = [];
        storage[pTCM].push(targetType);
        }
    }
    for (var prop in storage) {
        if (storage.hasOwnProperty(prop)){ }                
            newHtml += "<div style='margin:5px; padding:5px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #9C9C9C; font-size:95%'><div> <b>Page\/Component Published:</b> "+ title +
            " </div><div class='itpPath'>Path: "+ path +
            "</div><div class='itpTCM'>Item URI: " + "<input type='text' value=" + prop + " readonly>" + 
            "<input type='button' value='View Page' onclick='window.open(\"/WebUI/item.aspx?tcm=64#id=" + prop + "\")'> "+ 
            "</div><div class='itpPub'> Publication Target: " + storage[prop].join(', ') + 
            "</div></div>";
        }
    $j("#results").html(newHtml);
    $j("#loadingImage").hide();
}
```

unfortunately only reports the correct ID, and Publication grouping, but give only the last item in loop for the path and the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your storage object a little deeper so it looks something like:

```js
{
  "PcTmVal_1": {
    "targetType": [
      "ProdPreview",
      "TestPreview"
    ],
    "title": "testpage",
    "path": "somepath/url/"
  },
  "PcTmVal_2": {
    "targetType": [
      "ProdPreview",
      "TestPreview"
    ],
    "title": "anotherTitle",
    "path": "anotherpath/url/"
  }

}
```

Your first loop would look something like:

```js
if (storage[pTCM] === undefined) {
    storage[pTCM] = {
        targetType: [],
        title: title,
        path: path
    }
}

storage[pTCM].targetType.push(targetType);
```

Then in second loop replace

`+ title +`

with

`+ storage[prop].title +`

and instead of `storage[prop].join(', ')` it will be `storage[prop].targetType.join(', ')`